# Reference activeX control through worksheet variable (vba)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign a worksheet to a variable and then work with the controls on that sheet. I am really confused about why referencing the controls on the named variable wont work when I can from the sheet number.

```
Sub SheetNames()
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim pres As Worksheet
    Call NumSheets

    Set pres = Sheets("Presentation") 'Sheet18 (assignment works)
    Sheet18.lbSheets.Clear 'This works
    pres.lbSheets.Clear 'This fails (method or data member not found)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Worksheet` object is a generic "template" object type, which has only the "out of the box" properties which apply to all `Worksheet` objects. Your specific sheet `Sheet18` has controls added, and those controls are now parts of the sheet's object model, but they are *not* part of the generic `Worksheet` class: your sheet is now more like a specific "subclass" of Worksheet, so you cannot declare it as `Worksheet` and still access the controls via that reference.

However, you could declare it `As Sheet18` (the "subclass" for that specific sheet):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Sheet18

    Set sht = Sheet18
    Debug.Print sht.lbSheets.ListCount '<< nope - compile error because the
                                               '    Worksheet class has no
                                               '    "lbSheets" member

    Set sht2 = Sheet18
    Debug.Print sht2.lbSheets.ListCount '<< OK!
    'but you may as well skip the variable and just use
    Debug.Print Sheet18.lbSheets.ListCount

    'this also works if you know the sheet name and the control name
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Presentation")
    Debug.Print sht.OLEObjects("lbSheets").Object.ListCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Great that solves some of the confusion. But how would I go about to find the sheet by name? Like Public currentSheet As sheets("Presentation")

Comment: You don't know when you write the code which sheet that is?

Comment: No there can be more sheets added afterwards. Above has the same problem that sht still needs to be defined as sheet18. It could potentially change to sheet20

Comment: You can use my last example

Comment: understood. Thanks

Comment: If you add controls to a sheet with codename (not tab name) `Sheet18` then adding sheets later won't change that -  unless you update the code name, it will always be `Sheet18`